# creating events through zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api

in my server i downloaded and uploaded the zend gdata library.then as a test i created a seperated folder and checked whether its working. and yes it worked.so i kept the folder structure as it is and moved the files in to my app. then it gave me an error like this.even if i tried the same code which i used in the test folder, it gives me the same error.please help me.

error
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 400 [Line 1, Column 451, element gd:when] Badly formatted datetime' in /var/www/vhosts/eyepax.info/rsdesign.eyepax.info/emailApp2/Zend/Gdata/App.php:714 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/eyepax.info/[host]/emailApp2/Zend/Gdata.php(219): Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('POST', 'https://www.goo...', Array, 'performHttpRequest('POST', 'https://www.goo...', Array, 'performHttpRequest('POST', 'https://www.goo...', Array, 'performHttpRequest('POST', 'https://www.goo...', Array in /var/www/vhosts/eyepax.info/[host]/emailApp2/Zend/Gdata/App.php on line 714`

if this is a fault with the library, please tell me what to do..

in the test folder i have 2 files and the folder named Zend...i used the following code as a class and used it's example code to test it.and it worked. my problem is why is it not working in my app?

class=http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/28780.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i received this error for several reasons. my time offset was not correct.and the way i entered the time was incorrect aswell. it should be HH:MM:SS not HH.MM.SS . hope this helps someone